# Pangram Using Each Character Only Once

Tags: sentence

As a prank, I wish to arrange the keys on a coworker's keyboard to be a pangram, but in order to do so, the characters can only appear once.

I've done some googling and have not found a pangram that doesn't have repeat characters. With the limited number of vowels, I expect it might be impossible. If it is not impossible, is there one that makes sense?

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that a pangram that has no repeats exists. If one did it would be famous. If you want to explore this topic further I suggest *Puzzling* might be a better site. http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22784/three-voting-prisoners

Comment: I didn't find a pangram that is also an heterogram, i.e. a sentence in which no letter of the alphabet occurs more than once. A good heterogram (with 20 letters) is "The big dwarf only jumps" (Alain Brobecker). And "uncopyrightable" is a one word (15 letters)

Comment: Use the numerical keys for some more vowels ? @=a, 1=l, 0=o etc.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network; it is about puzzles rather than analysing normal English usage.

Comment: I'm voting to close, but @VenomFangs, try Googling this. I found http://www.fun-with-words.com/pang_example.html. There are some ridiculous ones out there, like _Mr. Jock, TV quiz PhD, bags few lynx_ and _TV quiz drag nymphs blew JFK cox_.

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of very odd pangrams (no repeated letters) referenced at this [site](http://www.rinkworks.com/words/pangrams.shtml) and the author states:

> Unfortunately, to my knowledge, there are no particularly clever 26
>   letter pangrams in English. Constructing a sentence that uses every
>   letter of the alphabet once and no more -- essentially an anagram of
>   the alphabet -- seems to require the use of acronyms, initials, and
>   strange punctuation. The most interesting I've seen is, "Glum
>   Schwartzkopf vex'd by NJ IQ."

There's also this answer in [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140210043053AAjRkRZ):

> Best Answer:  A sentence that contains every letter of the alphabet
>   at least once is called a pangram. People have constructed
>   26-letter-long pangrams using only words that can be found in an
>   unabridged dictionary, but they don't make a whole lot of sense. The
>   most famous example is "Cwm fjord bank glyphs vext quiz."